# Capitalize First Letter Of Each Name after Hyphen "-" and Space " "

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I'm currently using this String extension to Capitalize the letter of each word in a textField :

`"happy sunshine"`  `.toTitleCase()` gives `"Happy Sunshine"`

```
extension StringExtension on String {
  String toTitleCase() => replaceAll(RegExp(' +'), ' ')
      .split(' ')
      .map((str) => str.toCapitalized())
      .join(' ');
  String toCapitalized() =>
      length > 0 ? '${this[0].toUpperCase()}${substring(1).toLowerCase()}' : '';
}
```

but I'd also like to Capitalize letters that come after a hyphen `-` with the same `toTitleCase` method

ex : `"very-happy sunshine"`  `.toTitleCase()` would give `"Very-Happy Sunshine"`

Currently `.toTitleCase()` gives `"Very-happy Sunshine"` : (

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure a wizard with expert knowledge in regular expression can do this better but I think this solution solves your problem:

```
void main() {
  print('happy sunshine'.toTitleCase()); // Happy Sunshine
  print('very-happy sunshine'.toTitleCase()); // Very-Happy Sunshine
}

extension StringExtension on String {
  String toTitleCase() => replaceAllMapped(
      RegExp(r'(?<= |-|^).'), (match) => match[0]!.toUpperCase());
}
```

If you call the method a lot of times, you might consider having the `RegExp` as a cached value like:

```
extension StringExtension on String {
  static final RegExp _toTitleCaseRegExp = RegExp(r'(?<= |-|^).');

  String toTitleCase() =>
      replaceAllMapped(_toTitleCaseRegExp, (match) => match[0]!.toUpperCase());
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution with regex.

Comment: This solution is perfect - thank you for your answer too @ChiragBargoojar

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak your code as well. But I've used the same thing somewhere in my project so you can do something like this as well.

Working: First I'm creating an empty array looping through each character in a particular string and checking if `space` `(" ")` and `hyphen` `("-")` are `current_position - 1` then I'm making `current_position` to uppercase.

```
String capitalize(String s) {
  String result = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      result += s[i].toUpperCase();
    } else if (s[i - 1] == " ") {
      result += s[i].toUpperCase();
    } else if (s[i - 1] == "-") {
      result += s[i].toUpperCase();
    } else {
      result += s[i];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Consider using a `StringBuffer` if you are building a `String` object of multiple parts like you are doing here. It is much more efficient: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/StringBuffer-class.html